# Starting any Partition (WIN- Vista - Linux UBUNTU and and Mint- Debian) is only possible with CD -Grub2)

Tags: 15.04

My problem is, that Grub does not start Partitions using listed Partitions! My question is how to delete Grub2 loader functions and installing grub function new, so that the listed table of all Systems (installed) will be shown again!!! May be the problem started after update to UBUNTU 15-04!!!!
Thanks for giving me an answer! Where Grub starts is Gru Err 17 to see!!!
yours harryxy12345

Comment: Grub2 does not have error 17. That is from grub legacy. Better to see details, but this only works to install grub2. Grub legacy has not been used for about 6 years. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info